# How to resolve CS0246 ERROR: (The type or namespace name Error)?

Tags: c#

> The type or namespace name `CameraSpace` could not be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

What I have tried :

I have tested all the packages are installed properly but i still have this error shows. I added these new .NET frameworks,  namely,  `System.windows.forms` , `System.data.Linq`, `System.configuration` AND as i already said all the mentions packages are installed. I'm using **VS2015** and I'm not sure whether it's somehow related to VS or not. And needless to say, **I'm new to C#**. I spend too much time to solve it my own and watching some videos but all the errors are different with the same name 'CS0246' Please Please help me.

I have this following code :

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Baselabs.Statistics.Spaces;
using Baselabs.Statistics.Models.AdditiveNoise;
 

namespace DataFusion
{
    [DisplayName("..........")]
    [Description("..............")]
    class CameraMeasurementModel : MeasurementModel<CameraSpace, CVComponentsSpace>
```

**I also want to add**, `using Baselabs.Statistics.Spaces;` this package give the `CameraSpace` namespace

Comment: Put your cursor on `CameraSpace`. Press ctrl+.   Does it give you any suggestions?

Comment: @Crowcoder  thank you for the reply. It say _generate class `CameraSpace`_ but we are told from the class that this part of the code not need to be edited. I am not sure what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have added `CameraSpace` assembly reference correctly.

According to [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0246) :

> A type or namespace that is used in the program was not found. You
> might have forgotten to reference (-reference) the assembly that
> contains the type, or you might not have added the required using
> directive. Or, there might be an issue with the assembly you are
> trying to reference.

Track the possible cases in the page.

Comment: thanks for editing the post, i saw that `CameraSpace` assembled rightly. actually, we have this class name `MeasurementModel<>` and under that class, we have some properties that  model this `CameraSpace` , interestingly, i have another model called `RadarSpace` under the same class `MeasurementModel<>` but in a different file which has no error shown. _and_ most importantly, **with everything is same for the other members of my class, they have no error with this kind**

Comment: i have followed the docs , I guess the **error** is **namespace** but I couldn't resolve it. It is to be noted that `CameraSpace` is reference to assembly `Baselabs.Statistics.Examples.dll`. **I am not sure how to add and get this package in vs2015**

Comment: I really appreciate this effort, now i resolved this error just **adding reference to assembly**  `Baselabs.Statistics.Examples.dll` to Visual studio, it was the assembly that missing earlier.